# What LEGO set has the biggest box?

Tags: sets, packaging

I know the 2017 LEGO Star Wars Millennium Falcon is the biggest set in terms of piece count, but what is the biggest box a regular set ever came in?

By regular set I mean produced for the mass markets, and not something like [The ultimate battle for Chima](https://brickset.com/sets/BIGBOX-1/The-ultimate-battle-for-CHIMA) (just an example, not saying that it is the biggest box).

Comment: "Biggest" by what measure? Volume? Front area? Length? By volume <i think the MF will win (based on wat I've seen, so clearly not an answer), but 'I've bought an old First Lego League box, that was quite a bit longer, because the mat was rolled up on it.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h2VFD7STq_8 - Possibly useful

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As far as regular sets go (ie. no furniture or big-boxes like that Chima combo), the current UCS Millennium Falcon does appear to be the largest box by total volume.

### [75192-1 Millennium Falcon - UCS (2nd edition)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=75192-1)

54 x 45 x 39 cm = 94770 cm<sup>3</sup>

54 x 45 cm = 2430 cm<sup>2</sup>

[image]

The original UCS Millennium Falcon box was actually larger in 2 directions however, though the total volume is smaller.

## [10179-1 Millennium Falcon - UCS](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=10179-1)

64.39 x 47.63 x 19.69 cm = 60387.176333 cm<sup>3</sup>

64.39 x 47.63 cm = 3066.8957 cm<sup>2</sup>

[image]

There appear to be a number of sets that are larger in at-least one direction, see [this answer](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/12909) for the longest one identified so-far.

Comment: The Star Destroyer 75252 comes in a box that is similar in size to the large Millennium Falcon, but I can't find dimensions for it at the moment.

Comment: Bricklink lists the box of 75252 as being 53.5 x 46 x 38.7 cm = 95240,7 cm^3.

Comment: The box for the star destroyer from way back in 2002-ish (10030) comes in at 21 x 50 x 58.5cm, so 61425cm^2, beating the first falcon box in volume. Still nowhere near the 2nd edition falcon.

Comment: According to [Brickset](https://brickset.com/article/65066) 10294 Titanic as well as 10276 Colosseum boxes are "the same size as that of the Millennium Falcon and the Colosseum". Dimensions provided for Titanic are 58x48x38cm.

Answer (score 15):

Maybe straining the definition a little (although not too much, as at-least some of them did come with LEGO pieces), LEGO has in the past sold furniture.

I think all of these items were shipped disassembled, and I can't find much information on exactly how large the box they came in was and can't be sure what I did find is accurate, but I would imagine one of these items takes the cake (depending on your definition of largest).

### [4509g - 3-Seat Playtable](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?G=4509g) (101.5 x 74.5 x 18.5 cm)

[image]

### [5004063 - 3-Seat Playtable](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?G=5004063) (probably about same size)

[image]

### [5003468 - 3-Seat Playtable Creative Play Station Center Pack](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?G=5003468) (probably about same size)

[image]

### [5003483 - 3-Seat Playtable Creative Play Station Center Pack Duplo](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?G=5003483) (probably about same size)

[image]

### [IF-LTW2C - Activity Table and Chair Set](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?G=IF-LTW2C) (67.8 x 66.8 x 27.94 cm)

[image] [image]

Answer (score 12):

Straining the definition a little less than Alexander, some of the First LEGO League challenges came in boxes with the mat folded, making the box unexceptional, but some came in boxes with the mat rolled up.

According to bricklink the 2015 challenge came in a box that was 117 cm long. That is quite a bit more than any of the dimensions of the Millenium Falcon, which according to bricklink came in a box that was 54 x 45 x 39 cm. As I haven't seen other boxes that thick I'm going to guess that takes the price according to volume. (possibly discounting the furniture).

Another regular set that has a large box is [71043 Hogwarts Castle](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=167485#T=I), according to bricklink that box is 58.5 x 48.5 x 18.5 cm, that is a larger front then the Millenium Falcon, but under half the thickness.

I also believe the Millenium Falcon wins on weight, if that is what you meant by size, and can come in a "trolly box":
[image: Millenium Falcon wheelie box - Zhaph - Ben Duguid]

Comment: I'll have to go and measure my Robotics Invention System and LEGO Studios boxes, I think they're under 117cm, but would be good to confirm ;)

Comment: The 42082 all terrain crane is 57,8 x 47,8 x 19 cm. (Mine arrived earlier today.) About the same as the Hogwarts castle. I think the white Liebherr R9800 excavator model (42100) may have a slightly larger box, but I haven't seen that one for real.

Comment: I'm sure there are plenty of sets having boxes of about that size, probably even some in my piles. Hogwarts was just the first one I spotted, and going by part count it's second to the MF. Looking at the list of sets order by part count (it's trivial to get on bricklink), made me discover that the box of the original Taj Mahal is listed as 65.3 x 47.6 x 12.2 cm (the reissue is about the size of Hogwarts et.al.)

Comment: @Zhaph-BenDuguid: Thanks for adding that picture. Funny enough one of those trolley boxes was the first way I saw the MF. And that was also surrounded by other people who had been shopping LEGO, as on that picture.

Comment: Well, that was taken on my visit to the [LEGO house AFOL open day](https://bricks.meta.stackexchange.com/q/399/56) so we'd all been LEGO shopping ;)

Comment: I have an older Star Destroyer, and it weighed about 20 pounds if I recall.  So much that I was worried about it warping the top of my Mitsubishi 3- tube rear projector TV at the time (it was 18-20 inches deep).  Heaviest Lego set we ever bought.