# What LEGO set has the smallest box?

Tags: sets, packaging

Similar to [What Lego set has the biggest box?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/12907/what-lego-set-has-the-biggest-box) but probably more-challenging to answer, what LEGO set has the *smallest* box (either square or cubic dimensions work)?

I'm talking actual sets with an item number and an actual boxes, not polybags or sub-components in a set (like a minifig cape box).

Comment: Do you mean any set in a box regardless of retail sales? Or do you mean a commercial set intended for sale to a child or adult builder not employed by the Lego group or any affiliate? If it is the former then an answer may note be findable and of small interest. An answer to the second seemd more intriguing.

Comment: I have seen some Lego freebies which can be count as set as tehy ahev multiple pieces you need to connect. Are they going to count?

Comment: I think so long as it has a set item number, it would count.

Comment: yikes you cut the Hero of Time *close* right on 00.00. You know you have 59 seconds for that one.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I thought that promotional boxed sets were good candidates for the smallest box as well, as I own a [1630-1 Helicopter](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?O=1630-1) (which, incidentally, I got as a promotional gift for buying toothpaste at some point in the 90s IIRC), at 7 x 7 x 4.5 cm (220cm<sup>3</sup>/0.22 litres).

There are sets with similar dimensions as well, such as [5018-1 Gravity Games Promotional Set](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=5018-1) at 7 x 7.5 x 4 cm (210cm<sup>3</sup>/0.21 litres), [7912-1 Helicopter Promotional (Duracell)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=7912-1), [5017-1 Hockey Promotional set.](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=5017-1) and some others.

I thought those were the smallest in volume, but after a deeper search on bricklink I came up with a thinner 2.5cm ([281-1 1 x 2 and 3 x 2 Sloping Bricks, Red](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?O=281-1) with 8.6 x 6.2 x 2.5 cm / 133cm<sup>3</sup>/0.133 litres):

[image: 281-1 1 x 2 and 3 x 2 Sloping Bricks, Red]

And after delving in the sets with a low part cound, I came up with an even thinner 1.8cm box with [1222-2 1x1 round bricks](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?O=1222-2), at 7.5 x 5.5 x 1.8 cm (74.25cm<sup>3</sup>/0.074 litres) (same box size as [1241-2](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?O=1241-2), [1240-2](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?O=1240-2), [1230-2](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?O=1230-2) and possibly others):

[image: 1222-2 1x1 round bricks]

Also of note are the 1:87-scale cars from the 60s, like e.g. [265-2 1:87 Karmann Ghia with Garage](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?O=265-2):

[image: 265-2 1:87 Karmann Ghia with Garage]

The "box" itself is a transparent hollow brick, specifically [part number 721](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=721), 4x8 studs wide by 3 bricks high wrapped in a paper strip, which puts it at 3.2cm x 6.4cm x 3.04cm or 62.25cm<sup>3</sup>/0.062 litres. (Hey, you asked for the smallest box, not the smallest *cardboard* box!)

Apparently some of these 1:87-scale cars, e.g. [671-3 1:87 Vauxhall Victor Estate with Garage](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=671-3) were sold with an actual cardboard box around them, with listed dimensions of 3.2 x 3.2 x 6.5cm (66.56cm<sup>3</sup>/0.066 litres):

[image]

Comment: Wow! Great answer, and welcome to Bricks.SE!

Answer (score 5):

As with “biggest”, smallest also has different definitions (weight? Width? Volume?). Here are a few candidates:

[5005250 Party Banana Juice Bar](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=5005250-1&name=Party%20Banana%20Juice%20Bar&category=%5BCollectible%20Minifigures%5D%5B(Other)%5D#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D) - 8 x 4.5 x 11 cm (the Chicken version also qualifies)

[image]

[600-2 Police Patrol](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=600-2#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D) - 9.5 x 5.6 x 3.6 cm

[image]

I don’t have a link or box picture, but the Dutch store opening gift Windmill comes in a pretty small box as well.

EDIT: Michael Verschaeve pointed me to [the BL entry for the Windmill](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=Amsterdam-1#T=S&O=). 14.5 x 14.5 x 4.5 doesn’t exactly make the box a good candidate.

[image]

Comment: https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=Amsterdam-1#T=S&O={%22iconly%22:0}